# IntelliJ: How to configure dictionary that is already under version control?

Tags: intellij-idea

We have a dictionary in version control under the path `eclipse/spelling/german.dic`. The only way I know to use that dictionary within IDEA is adding it as a Custom Dictionary.

So every developer has to configure the dictionary by hand after cloning the repository. Is there a way to avoid that? Can there be an `.idea/where.ever`, that tells IDEA to use the dictionary located under the given project-local path?

Answer (score 11):

**Application-level dictionary** can be found at: {IDE installation directory}/config/options/cachedDictionary.xml

**Project-level dictionary**: {Project root}/.idea/dictionaries/%username%.xml

The dictionaries files are created by IDEs automatically when you apply "Save To" quick-fix or modify **Settings | Spelling | Accepted words table**.

Additionally dictionaries files may be opened in editor from **Settings | Spelling | Dictionaries table** by clicking Edit button as well:
[image]

For more details please visit: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spelling.html

Only project-level dictionaries may be shared between developers via VCS. Please see [How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839).

Comment: I don't know when exactly this was changed, but for my 2022 version of PyCharm the dictionary file was named `spellchecker-dictionary.xml`